# How can DOM DocumentFragments help in optimizing dom manipulation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are thinking of using  `DOMDocumentFragments` as a candidate for optimizing the dom manipulation code .  What do you guys think ?

Comment: I think that's a great story. Good luck. I also think this question is not constructive as *We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, see the FAQ for guidance.*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not `DOMDocumentFragment` by itself that optimizes the dom manipulation, it's the fact that document fragments are disconnected from the main document, so manipulating them doesn't trigger any possibly heavy graphical updates on the screen.

You can also do it without document fragments just by using a disconnected node.

Comment: but at some point we do have to sync between the changes that we make to DOMDocumentFragment to the main document . So still it opens the posiibility of "heavy graphical updates on the screen." .Don't you agree ?

Comment: @Subhra Yes, I agree. I never said anything on the contrary.

Comment: @Esailja :-) Correct me if I am wrong . I think that the actual number of append to the main dom is reduced by using DOMDocumentFragment . You keep on doing the small append to the DOMDocumentFragment and when you are done you apply the update at once to the main document. This is what makes the DOMDocumentFragment to optimize the DOM manipulation code

Comment: @Subhra yes but you could do that with any disconnected node, not just DOM fragments.

Comment: I agree . I just found out this [blog by John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/). May be it will be helpful. +1 for your answer and follow up comments.

Comment: @Subhra: a `DocumentFragment` only really helps when you need to insert several sibling nodes at a single location in the document. A `DocumentFragment` allows you to do this in a single operation, which a single disconnected element does not.